# Worksheet without Workbook or Application?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I don't know if this makes sense or not but is it possible to create/edit an Excel Worksheet object without having a Workbook or Excel.Application object?

Comment: You may have to supply additional detail...

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Maybe if we understand more about your problem we can suggest potential alternatives.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the requirement and context please? However the short answer will always be No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need a Workbook object to nest your Worksheet object.
But you can create a Workbook without having an Excel.Application.

Comment: How do you create a Workbook without an Excel Application? Why is this allowed but not the Sheet without Workbook?

Comment: You can create Workbooks in other applications (SQL, Powerpoint, etc.) using OLEDB. But you need a Workbook object to store a Worksheet.
Real life example. You can grow a lettuce in water (no need to be in earth), but you can't grow lettuce leafs without lettuce roots.